# Most efficient way to make a tileable background from a single image that is compatible with any size of canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, background

I am making a gravity simulator in javascript, and I wanted to have a nice space background that moved as the camera did. What is the best, most efficient way to do this on a canvas?

I have an offset on all my objects, drawing them relative to the offsets. I want this background to move with the offset, but then return to 0,0 when it moves too far (gives the illusion of movement forever, without drawing infinite images). I want this background to be interchangeable, and have a default, blank color.

Comment: you can do it with any image but putting a mirror image to the right, a flipped image under, and a mirror+flipped under and to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this on the `canvas`, but it will be faster to draw it in a `div` under the canvas.  That way you don't need to redraw the background every single time you want to animate anything.  You can use css to tile the image, make it move (if you need), etc.  Otherwise, if you really need to do it on the `canvas` to animate the background with the game, you can use [`drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage).